# Factor analysis on ordinal data

Tags: r, psych, factor-analysis

I'm trying to do some factor analysis on some ordinal data I have, i.e. Likert scale questionnaires going from 0 to 5.

I have been reading about how this should be approached since it is not continuous data. I then found the following paper:

http://pareonline.net/pdf/v19n5.pdf

And from that, even though he uses a different program than R, it seems that when dealing with ordinal data, it is a must to use the polychoric correlation, and he also suggests minimum rank factor analysis for the factor method. I'm a bit unsure if the Promin rotation he suggests is available in R ?

Anyway, when trying to perform this analysis in R I try to use the following code from the `psych` package:

```
fa(data, cor = "poly", fm = "minrank")
```

However, when doing so I get the error (even if I put in the term `nfactors = <some number>`:

```
Error in glb.algebraic(S) : 'Cov' is not symmetric
```

I also get a lot of warnings saying `In log(P) : NaNs produced`.

I have no idea what is wrong here, and how to fix it ? My data set (the one I'm using now) is just a 219 x 19 matrix with values going from 0 to 5, and no blank cells at all.

Am I doing something wrong here, or...?

EDIT:
The header of the data:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 19
  `Pt id`    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q7    Q8   Q10   Q12   Q15   Q17   Q18   Q20   Q21   Q22   Q23   Q24
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     304     5     4     5     0     3     5     0     4     1     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
2     474     5     1     5     0     3     5     0     4     1     4     0     0     0     4     4     0
3     509     5     5     4     5     3     5     0     4     1     0     0     4     4     4     4     4
4     232     5     1     4     0     3     1     0     4     0     0     0     0     0     3     3     0
5     254     5     2     3     0     3     4     0     2     1     0     0     0     1     2     2     0
6     372     5     2     3     0     3     2     0     2     0     0     1     0     0     4     4     0
# ... with 2 more variables: Q25 <dbl>, Q26 <dbl>
```

And all the data from `dput`:

```
structure(list(`Pt id` = c(304, 474, 509, 232, 254, 372, 388, 
493, 283, 296, 305, 468, 257, 258, 362, 353, 471, 210, 213, 234, 
314, 319, 332, 336, 339, 350, 357, 359, 363, 365, 370, 385, 411, 
417, 436, 455, 461, 462, 495, 521, 317, 211, 204, 299, 373, 405, 
423, 328, 349, 497, 202, 207, 215, 239, 245, 250, 293, 294, 297, 
303, 310, 326, 341, 369, 379, 416, 430, 433, 442, 448, 456, 477, 
486, 503, 520, 337, 382, 407, 498, 249, 262, 266, 438, 510, 320, 
309, 267, 292, 335, 206, 216, 237, 251, 269, 324, 343, 355, 360, 
375, 395, 399, 403, 404, 412, 424, 440, 457, 500, 288, 244, 279, 
311, 342, 389, 447, 508, 291, 318, 439, 209, 224, 229, 275, 277, 
330, 368, 390, 394, 406, 459, 469, 476, 479, 523, 201, 203, 205, 
218, 219, 222, 225, 226, 227, 231, 236, 238, 242, 247, 248, 260, 
261, 264, 271, 272, 278, 285, 298, 300, 301, 306, 323, 327, 329, 
331, 333, 340, 345, 347, 351, 356, 358, 361, 364, 366, 367, 371, 
376, 377, 378, 384, 397, 398, 400, 401, 402, 408, 413, 414, 419, 
420, 425, 431, 437, 441, 444, 450, 451, 452, 453, 458, 460, 463, 
466, 470, 483, 487, 492, 502, 505, 506, 511, 515, 517), Q1 = c(5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 
5, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 
4, 4, 0, 3, 1, 4, 3, 0, 3, 5, 5, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 
4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 2, 5, 4, 1, 1, 0, 3, 5, 1, 
5, 0, 3, 1, 5, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 3, 
0, 3, 5, 5, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 0, 1, 
3, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
2, 3, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 
5, 4, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), Q2 = c(4, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 4, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Q3 = c(5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q4 = c(0, 0, 5, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Q7 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q8 = c(5, 5, 5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 1, 
    2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 5, 
    3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 
    4, 0, 1, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 
    4, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 
    3, 2, 5, 4, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 3, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 5, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 1, 5, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 0, 
    5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
    2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Q12 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 2, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
    4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 
    0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
    2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    4, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q15 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q17 = c(4, 4, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 
    2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
    3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0, 1, 
    1), Q18 = c(4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 
    3, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0), Q20 = c(4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
    1, 4, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 
    0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
    2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
    0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q21 = c(4, 
    0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
    0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), Q22 = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 
    2, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 
    1, 4, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 2, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    4, 2, 1, 0, 4, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q23 = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 
    4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 4, 
    1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 
    2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 
    1, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
    1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
    0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0), Q24 = c(4, 
    0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 
    1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
    0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), Q25 = c(3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 
    3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q26 = c(3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Pt id", 
"Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q7", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q15", "Q17", 
"Q18", "Q20", "Q21", "Q22", "Q23", "Q24", "Q25", "Q26"), row.names = c(NA, 
-213L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So basically some questionnaires/Likert scale values coupled to a patient ID.

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample dataset?

Comment: I have added the data to the OP.